# Mysterious delegate arithmetics in ObservableCollection events implementatons

Tags: .net, events, delegates

Been doing some reasearch of ObservableCollection implementation I've found some code I can't understand.
Here is code fragment decompiled by .Net Reflector:

```
[NonSerialized]
private NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
[NonSerialized]
private PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
{
  add
  {
    this.PropertyChanged += value;
  }
  remove
  {
    this.PropertyChanged -= value;
  }
}

public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
{
  add
  {
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler changedEventHandler = this.CollectionChanged;
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler comparand;
    do
    {
      comparand = changedEventHandler;
      changedEventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>(ref this.CollectionChanged, comparand + value, comparand);
    }
    while (changedEventHandler != comparand);
  }
  remove
  {
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler changedEventHandler = this.CollectionChanged;
    NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler comparand;
    do
    {
      comparand = changedEventHandler;
      changedEventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler>(ref this.CollectionChanged, comparand - value, comparand);
    }
    while (changedEventHandler != comparand);
  }
}

protected virtual event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
{
  add
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler changedEventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
    PropertyChangedEventHandler comparand;
    do
    {
      comparand = changedEventHandler;
      changedEventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(ref this.PropertyChanged, comparand + value, comparand);
    }
    while (changedEventHandler != comparand);
  }
  remove
  {
    PropertyChangedEventHandler changedEventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
    PropertyChangedEventHandler comparand;
    do
    {
      comparand = changedEventHandler;
      changedEventHandler = Interlocked.CompareExchange<PropertyChangedEventHandler>(ref this.PropertyChanged, comparand - value, comparand);
    }
    while (changedEventHandler != comparand);
  }
}
```

What I can't understand is why there are two (public and private) implementations of PropertyChanged, but only one (protected) of CollectonChanged? 
And what's the purpose of that delegate arithmetics in do-while cycles? Why not just "this.Property += value" like in private implementation of PropertyChanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using a decompiler to look at framework code, use the actual source code you can get from the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx) instead.  The source for this class is located in the Source.NET 4.5\4.6.0.0\net\fx\src\CompMod\System\Collections\ObjectModel\ObservableCollection.cs directory.  You'll then see what the CollectionChanged event *really* looks like:

```
    //------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the collection changes, either by adding or removing an item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// see <seealso cref="INotifyCollectionChanged"/>
    /// </remarks>
    [field:NonSerializedAttribute()]
    public virtual event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
```

That's all, there is no more code for that.

The decompiler isn't smart enough to recognize the auto-generated code that the C# compiler generates to implement the event and thus doesn't know how to collapse it back to the *real* C# code for the event.  At least part of the reason for this deficiency is that this changed in .NET 4.0.  The do-while loop is new, it is there to ensure that event subscription is *thread-safe*.  The older way used the [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] attribute to make it thread-safe.  Which has a flaw, it locks on *this*, a practice that can cause unintentional dead-lock.

And yes, there are two PropertyChanged events.  One is the explicit implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, it just uses the other.  This was done to ensure that the event isn't public, as would normally happen when you inherit an interface, it is re-declared as *protected*.